# TortoiseGIT not showing in menu Windows 11

Tags: tortoisegit

I have installed Tortoise GIT into Windows 11 and its not showing at all in the context menus, both the normal menu or the windows 11 menu

I have uninstalled and reinstalled loads of times

Has anyone had this?  Its a major pain for me as I use it constantly

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: On the context menu, click `Show more options` to see the TortoiseGit menu items

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, see https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues/3975 and seems to be based on a change in Windows 11 (cf. [Why is IExplorerCommand::Invoke() no longer being called?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74226129/3906760)).

A new preview release will be available soon.